# Storing an object with related model results in IntegrityError: null value violates not null constraint

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I am having the following problem with using Django and Tastypie. Strangely for about a year or so the following worked flawlessly. Now when I am trying to edit the `Car` on an `Owner` and store the `Owner` I get this error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "car_id" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (55, test, 53, null).

I know that I can alter the field `car` on the model `Wheel` to nullable but I definitely want to keep this relation defined. Strangely when I changed the field to nullable for testing, the id gets set in my database. Then when I am doing another edit the database entry isn't updated but instead a new entry gets created. This entry again contains the right id but the old entry loses it and the field is left blank.

This is what table `wheel` looks like after editing it on the Car object two times:

```
postgres=# TABLE wheel;
id | value | wheel_type_id | car_id
---+-------+---------------+--------
53 | abc   |            53 |
54 | def   |            53 |     11
(2 rows)
```

Instead my desired result would be this:

```
postgres=# TABLE wheel;
id | value | wheel_type_id | car_id
---+-------+---------------+--------
53 | def   |            53 |     11
(1 row)
```

Models:

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Car(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField('Owner', null=True, related_name='car',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ready = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Wheel(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='wheel',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wheel_type = models.ForeignKey(WheelType, related_name='names',
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Tastypie resources:

```
class OwnerResource(ModelResource):
    car = fields.ToOneField('CarResource', null=True, full=True,       
                             attribute='car')

class CarResource(ModelResource):
    wheels = fields.ToManyField('WheelResource', 'wheels', null=True,
                                 blank=True, full=True)

class WheelResource(ModelResource):
    wheeltype = fields.ForeignKey('WheelTypeResource',   
                                  'wheel_type', full=False)


    class Meta:
        queryset = Wheel.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        ordering = ['modified']
        excludes = ['id']
        include_resource_uri = False
        limit = 100
        authorization = Authorization()
        always_return_data = True
```

Example request:

```
fetch("http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/v1/owner/1/", {
    "credentials": "include",
    "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "accept-language": "de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "x-csrftoken": "3sarlkh0giQ7yqhTSclCivfEsSvs5R3a7gTw0pw293v80ypCT6n3Drm8AhQDx3GB"
    },
    "referrer": "http://0.0.0.0:8000/backend/owner/1",
    "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
    "body": "{\"car\":{\"resource_uri\":\"/api/v1/car/3/\",\"wheels\":[{\"wheeltype\":\"/api/v1/wheeltype/identificationInfo/\",\"value\":\"abc\"}]},\"resource_uri\":\"/api/v1/owner/1/\",}",
    "method": "PATCH",
    "mode": "cors"
});
```

Does anyone have a clue why the `car_id` is not defined when saving the object, but when making the field nullable it still gets set? Starting to think this could be a bug of Tastypie or Django.

Comment: If you have a null constraint on car_id. Then why do you set `null=True` on the `ToOneField` in OwnerResource?

Comment: Also, can you show us the REST call you send?

Comment: `null=True` allows for the Owner having a Car or not. In my models this is represented by the reverse `OneToOneField` that each car can belong to one Owner. But an Owner not necessarily needs to have a Car defined. The IntegrityError arrises because of the WheelResource. I updated my question with an example request. I have to say that this is only an excerpt of a real request for demonstration purposes. Even when extending the WheelResource with a `car` field and assigning the specific Car instance via custom hydrate method does not help to successfully update the database.

Comment: have you tried adding `related_name='wheel'` to wheels field of CarResource as described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14393333/3130972? The docs indicate a similar situation to what you've described https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html?highlight=tomanyfield#related-name